# Django admin assets are not avaiable on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, django, elastic-beanstalk

I created a basic Python Django environment on AWS. My project is generated with `django-admin startproject michaelmalura`. I added an app with `django-admin startapp blog`.

After i publish my project with `eb deploy` everything on the frontend works fine. But the backend does not show any styles.

**settings.py**

...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog'
]
```

...

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**django.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "michaelmalura.settings"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "michaelmalura/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

**Admin error**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://michaelmalura.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/admin/css/base.css`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to fix this. I removed the .. from STATIC_ROOT

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```